# Need file descriptor for socket in UDP

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

In my tcp program i have an int called fd, fd is set = to the file descriptor returned when accept() is called. I now want to make this code be udp instead of tcp, but udp has no accept() so how do i get the value accept() would have returned, but in udp?

Comment: Since a udp socket is exclusively message oriented, it can't really  take the place of a file handle.

Answer (score 3):

UDP is connectionless, so `listen()` and `accept()` are not used (and `connect()` merely assigns a static binding so `send()`/`recv()` can be used instead of `sendto()`/`recvfrom()`, thus allowing the OS perform some filtering of packets for you).  You get a UDP descriptor from `socket()` and then send/receive on it as needed, where `sendto()` (or `connect()`+`send()`) tells it where to send an outbound packet to, and `recvfrom()` (or `connect()`+`recv()`) tells you where an inbound packet came from.  A single UDP socket can send packets to multiple clients using `sendto()`, and receive packets from multiple clients using `recvfrom()`.

Comment: so in server, if i have fd = new socket(), can i use write(fd, message, messagelength); and have message written out in the client terminal? in my tcp server, i have fd = accept(socket, , ) and then write(fd, message, messagelength); and message gets written out in the client terminal, will the same work for udp?

Comment: Yes, in UDP you can write using the descriptor from `socket()`. `write()` would only work if you use `connect()` to associate the socket with a specific peer IP/Port, otherwise `write()` won't know where to send to, you would have to use `sendto()` instead.

Comment: Again, UDP is connection-less, there is no "connected" state. You need to stop thinking in terms of client and server when dealing with UDP. It does not apply. There is only messages, any peer can send a message to any other peer at any time. A "connection" is created when two peers exchange message with each other, and the "connection" is gone when no more messages are exchanged. I mention `connect()` **only** because it allows you to associate a UDP socket with a specific peer, but that is **optional**. Most uses of UDP do not make sure of that feature. You can send a message at any time.

Comment: Typically, a "client" sends an initial message when it wants to "connect" to a "server". When the "server" receives a new message from an unknown peer, it keeps track of that peer. When the peer stops sending messages after a period of time, the "server" assumes the peer is gone and stops tracking it. During that time frame, they have a "connection" with each other. Notice my use of quotation marks. This is strictly from a logical protocol standpoint, since there is no actual *connection* as far as UDP is concerned.

Comment: I already answered that - use the descriptor from `socket()` and use `connect()` so `read()` and `write()` know which peer to communicate with. But you will end up having to edit the function anyway, because UDP has different semantics than TCP. Your existing `read()`/`write()` logic is very likely going to break one way or another.